# How do I deal with Azure Management API having no SLA?

Tags: azure

It looks like there's no SLA for Azure Management API (correct me if I'm wrong). The Management Portal likely uses Management API under the hood.

So it means that should anything go wrong with the Management API service I'll be unable to deploy fixes, change service settings and scale the service (which is really important should more load come) and there's no SLA to cover this.

How do I build a reliable service if I have to rely on Management API which looks like having no SLA?

Comment: You're correct that there're no SLAs associated with Service Management API. Not only Windows Azure Portal but Azure Management Cmdlets and a lot of other tools and services use this API for performing management operations. If this service goes down, we're indeed left high and dry. I would also be very interested in hearing about this from somebody from Microsoft.